# Circuit Review Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I know that there is a Code Review site on Stack Exchange. Where would one post electrical schematics for review? Or is that even a thing?

In other words, CodeReview.Stackexchange is to programming as ___________.Stackexchange is to EE.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mureinik already proposed the best thing you can/should do regarding your proposal.

But as a user of [Electronics SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) I can assure you that it is the proper SE site to address Schematics Review questions. See [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/35757/schematic-review) and [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/31529/li-poly-battery-charger-with-protection-schematic-review) for examples.

The "schematic review" kind of questions don't appear extremely often there, so opening a SE for that doesn't sound reasonable at this point.

Comment: Definitely. The only reason we have Code Review is because Stack Overflow decided that they didn't want those types of questions. The _less_ you fragment communities choked full of expertise, the better, so don't go making a site unless you've got great questions and just keep hitting a wall with them.

Comment: I am just worried about getting yelled at by moderators when I post something in the wrong place.

Comment: @Billylegota Your worries aren't totally unjustified on SE :D But don't be discouraged from asking a schematic review question on Electronics SE. Before you post your question(s) please do take a good look at 2 example questions I posted up in my answer (and also other similar ones you may come across). See how they are formatted, what your input should be and what kind of answers you can expect. Certainly I must point out that more than posting a schematic and asking "is this ok?" will be welcome eg write what part of schematic you find "potentially troublesome", issues you fear could arise..

Answer (score 7):

The correct place to recommend opening new StackExchange sites is [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/). If you think such a site would have a viable community, just [propose a new technology site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/create?category=technology), and if it gains the appropriate amount of traction, it'll open.